# Custom message on Add/Remove members

Tags: apex, exception, popup, label, collaborationgroup

I have implemented an apex method that prevents a certain profile (let's call it **A profile**) from being removed from a Collaboration Group. The apex code works fine but I don't know if there's a way to show a custom message after the user clicks the (x) icon (see screenshot below, besides the Manager word).

The code is simple, a method called in a before delete trigger on CollaborationGroupMember object checks the profile of the member to be deleted and should throw an error message if the member's profile is **A**. The problem is that using addError on User, CollaborationGroupMember or CollaborationGroup objects throws an exception *sObject does not allow errors*. And, as long as I know, I can't use a Visualforce page since that (x) button can't be replaced.

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Without code samples, I'm going to have to just take a guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong object and/or field. Here's code that I've just written up that proves it works:

```
trigger preventDelete on CollaborationGroupMember (before delete) {
    for(CollaborationGroupMember g: Trigger.old) {
        g.addError('You cannot delete me');
    }
}
```

The page will display this error message correctly once the user accepts the initial attempt to remove the member.